# $F(x)=\int_{a}^x f(t) dt$ is uniformly continuous where $f\in C[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $F(x)=\int_{a}^x f(t) dt$ is uniformly continuous, where $f\in C[a,b]$

Can I say here $f(t): t\in [a,b]$ is bounded?

Does this $F(x)=\int_{a}^x f(t) dt $,     imply $f$ is bounded? 
What I think is , since the integral of $f(t)$ over a set exist which if $F(x)$ , this means $f(t)$ has to be bounded. 
I am not sure, my intuition says that.
Any examples or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can show $|F(x)-F(y)|\leq M|x-y|$, where $ M =\sup|f|$ over $[a,b]$, which exits due to uniform continuity of $f$. Hence $F$ is Lipschitz, hence uniform continuous

Comment: My question whether the sup of $f$ exists or not? If it exists , it is pretty clear.

Comment: @Santosh It exists, since $f$ is continuous over a closed bounded interval, hence uniform continuous, and bounded.

Comment: Uniform continuity does not always imply the boundedness. $f(x)=x$ from $ R \to R$.

Comment: @Santosh, but $\Bbb R$ is not compact, which is not what John is driving at.

Comment: Yes, I get it , image of a compact set under the continuous function is compact , so is bounded , thus the supremum exist.